# django cache REST API Urls issue

Tags: django, curl, django-rest-framework, django-cache, django-caching

I have followed the solution provided in [Stack overflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320008/how-to-cache-django-rest-framework-api-calls) & it is working perfectly when i use this from my browser. However, when i tried hitting that url with curl, it doesn't cache for the browser..

Let me explain.

> If i hit a url like `example.org/results?limit=7` from my chrome, it
>   takes `8-10 seconds` to load & successive hits takes time in
>   `milliseconds`

So what i did is call this `URL` with the `curl` command; but it didn't use the cached data & created the cache again.

So i found out the issue is with the `arg` parameter in the below code as it contains the browser headers in `WSGIRequest` object which is being used in caching key as it contains the headers also which i don't require for caching. This is failing my purpose of curl requests to create the cache automatically from `celery task`.

```
@method_decorator(cache_page(60 * 60 * 24))
def dispatch(self, *arg, **kwargs):
    print(arg)
    print(kwargs)
    return super(ProfileLikeHistoryApi, self).dispatch(*arg, **kwargs)
```

What can i do is to pass only the `kwargs` to create the cache or any other alternative by which i can do cache for urls only not the headers

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR; Remove method decorator and cache manually

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes, force_text, iri_to_uri
import hashlib

def dispatch(self, *arg, **kwargs):

    if self.request.method == 'GET' or self.request.method == 'HEAD':
        key = hashlib.md5(force_bytes(iri_to_uri(self.request.build_absolute_uri()))))
        data = cache.get(key)
        if not data:
            data = super(ProfileLikeHistoryApi, self).dispatch(*arg, **kwargs)  
            cache.set(key, data, 60*60*24)
            return data

   return super(ProfileLikeHistoryApi, self).dispatch(*arg, **kwargs)
```

### cache_page decorator

Yes, you are right that cache page decorator will decide what to cache based on the headers. However only '[vary](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/cache.py#L38)' headers are supposed to have an impact.

Secondly only GET and HEAD requests are cached (and cachable) so that's why in the above code we check the method first.

### md5

You might have heard that is obsolete and not secure. That maybe so for cryptography, but it does not apply in our case. The hash generation scheme used here is exactly the same as used by django's [_generate_cache_key](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/cache.py#L324) but we leave out the headers from the equation.

### That one guy get's a slow page

Every day there will be one guy who get's a slow page because the cache has expired. Everyone else will get stale data. Data that's as old as 23 hours and 59 minutes.

Consider running a background process or a cron that runs this tasks in the background say every 6 hours and freshens the cache.

Now that maybe a bit difficult with memcached, because it doesn't provide an easy way to find all keys with a specific pattern, but if you used redis or cached in the db, it becomes easy.