# Django, Redis: Where to put connection-code

Tags: python, django, redis

I have to query redis on every request in my Django-app. Where can I put the setup/ connection routine (`r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379)`) so that I can access and reuse the connection without having to instantiate a new connection in my views?

Comment: Create a connection in django settings file. If you had any doubts refer here https://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/

Comment: I don't see where they are creating the connection at the provided link

Comment: scroll down and check it in the User Guide topic https://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/#_user_guide

Comment: this does not instantiate the connection

Comment: It will work, i don't know why it's not working for you. One more time read the doc properly

Comment: How can I access the connection in my views then?

Comment: Please give me a reason for downvoting so that I can improve my question-quality.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to Settings file for creating connection,

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient"
         },
        "KEY_PREFIX": "example"
    }
}

# Cache time to live is 15 minutes.
CACHE_TTL = 60 * 15
```

View level Cache, It will cache the query response(data)

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

class TestApiView(generics.ListAPIView):
     serializer_class = TestSerializer

     @method_decorator(cache_page(60))
     def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
          return super(TestApiView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Template level cache,

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.cache.backends.base import DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from .services import get_recipes_with_cache as get_recipes

CACHE_TTL = getattr(settings, 'CACHE_TTL', DEFAULT_TIMEOUT)


@cache_page(CACHE_TTL)
def recipes_view(request):
     return render(request, 'index.html', {
         'recipes': get_recipes()
     })
```

For any doubts refer this links

1. [How to cache Django Rest Framework API calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320008/how-to-cache-django-rest-framework-api-calls)
2. https://github.com/realpython/django-redis-cache
3. https://boostlog.io/@nixus89896/setup-caching-in-django-with-redis-5abb7d060814730093a2eebe

Comment: I don't want caching. I want to access redis for a different reason